# Is there a way to run test cases in parallel in different ec2 instances(eg. Run set of 90 cases across three AWS machines)

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

Using testng factory and Data provider annotations we have set of test cases that needs to be executed in parallel using selenium grid. As of now we have say for example three AWS instances with the IPs required. For now, we are able to run set of cases in parallel in single AWS instance. i.e able to run set of 30 cases in parallel in single instance.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<suite name="reg_tests" parallel="tests" thread-count="90">
    <test name="sanity_01" parallel="instances" thread-count="30">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.X.Y"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="sanity_02" parallel="instances" thread-count="30">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.X.Y1"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="sanity_03" parallel="instances" thread-count="30">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.X.Y2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Have properties file where we get the IP of the machine where we want to run which is obviously pointing to single AWS machine.

```
  WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(url), 
  desiredCapabilities);
```

url -  IP of the AWS machine.
So, the above code directs to run in single machine. So, now is there a way to ask the selenium grid to run in all three Grid machines which are already set up for executing test cases. Since the thread maintenance are managed internally, can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course. But it is depend on the hub.
The node must able to register to the hub successfully.

Note that your selenium code target to hub only not to node and hub then decide to whom they need to redirect as per the capability set by you.

For an example if your **sanity_01** having capabilities of chrome and when you target to the hub, the hub understood the capablity and redirect your code to node machine/ec2 which is register for chrome

```
     baseURL = "http://demo.xyz.com/test/";
     hubURL = "http://192.168.43.223:4444/wd/hub";
     DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
     capability.setBrowserName("chrome");
     capability.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);
     driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL), capability);
```

In above code the hub is `hubURL = "http://192.168.43.223:4444/wd/hub";` and as capability is set to chrome, it will send it to chrome node.
if 2 chrome node added to hub then it will redirect to anyone as per the node availability

Comment: Okay. So we need to have a single hub in any one machine ec2 and nodes in 3 aws registeted to the same hub. Let me try it out. Thanks

Comment: yes, hub will be same and nodes can be a same machine or nodes can be other ec2 machine, the main point is the nodes able to register to hub successfully. ideally node we put in separate ec2 if we need to invoke more browser, its depend the machine RAM capacity

Comment: Works fine. Just curious to know if we run 90 instances using one hub and three hubs with 90 instances ,then execution time difference will be there? If so, will it be huge? Provided we have three machines with same capacity to handle the request(ram of 64gb)

Comment: 3 nodes with 90 instance is itself huge, you can use https://www.browserstack.com/ service they handle such situations for automation projects